# Eclipse Embedded Maven installation disappeared after switching from External

Tags: eclipse, maven, external

Last Eclipse released comes with Maven embedded, but in our project we used to switch to our external installation of it.

[image: Eclipse Maven External installation]

One of the members started to use the embedded one, and it worked fine, so I removed the External entry and tried to switch back to the Embedded one, but it seems it has disappeared from the installations list.

[image: Eclipse Maven Embedded installation disappeared]

And trying to Add it via menu, it does not work, as I guess is looking for an External one.
This is an image from the Net, that I guess is what I should get, but I'm missing the Embedded one in my Eclipse Maven Preferences.

[image]

By the way, I'm using:

*Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819*

Answer (score 21):

Simply remove the external maven installation. When you restart eclipse, the embedded maven will reappear.

Comment: how did you know this?

Comment: It worked and both the embedded and external were available, Thanks